# A very flexible visitor pattern with no run-time overheads

Tags: c++, c++11

**BACKGROUND**

I am working on an implementation of the `A*` algorithm that would be employed by academic researchers (such as myself) to experiment with novel variants of `A*`. The two main design goals are: total flexibility (i.e. any variant can be implemented) and no run-time overheads, which means that all the user-defined handlers must be bound at compile time.

My first attempt was to use *policy-based design* as described by the **Modern C++ Design** (Alexandrescu, 2001), but coming up with orthogonal policies quickly became a challenge.

In this post, I would like to share a new design **that I am very much excited about**. This design is **not** specific to `A*`, so it might be relevant to others.

**DESIGN GOALS**

The starting point is visitors, of course, somewhat similar to the visitors that the `Boost Graph Library` uses for its algorithms. A *visitor* specifies a *handler* for one or more events generated by the algorithm. For the purposes of this project, the handlers must possess the following properties:

- To achieve maximum flexibility, a handler must have access to the data that the algorithm makes available to the visitors.
- Handlers are bound to events at compile-time.
- A handler can return a value that provides feedback to the algorithm. (In the case of `A*`, when a node is selected, the handler of that event might tell the algorithm that this node should not be expanded, but should be re-inserted into the *Open List*, e.g. because the handler was able to increase the cost of the node). A handler can return `void` as well, in which case there should be no run-time cost for handling the return value.

**IMPLEMENTATION**

We define a base class for visitors with the handlers that do nothing:

```
struct VisitorBase {
    template <class Algorithm>
    static void OnEvent1(Algorithm &alg) {(void)alg;}

    template <class Algorithm>
    static void OnEvent2(Algorithm &alg) {(void)alg;}
};
```

The `alg` parameter gives the visitors access to:

- All the data that the algorithm makes available and
- The return types for the events.

A user might define a visitor as follows:

```
struct UserVisitor: public VisitorBase {
    template <class Algorithm>
    static typename Algorithm::ResultOfHandlingEvent1 OnEvent1(Algorithm &alg) {
        std::cout << "In VisitorForEvent1! data1 = " << alg.data1 << std::endl;
        return Algorithm::ResultOfHandlingEvent1::EVENT1_ACTION1;
    }
};
```

Here is a class that defines the things available to the visitors:

```
struct AlgorithmBase {
    enum class ResultOfHandlingEvent1 {EVENT1_ACTION1, EVENT1_ACTION2};
    enum class ResultOfHandlingEvent2 {EVENT2_ACTION1, EVENT2_ACTION2};
    int data1 = 5;
};
```

Finally, an algorithm would look like this:

```
template <class Visitor>
struct Algorithm: AlgorithmBase {
    void run() {
        constexpr bool ReturnTypeFlagOfOnEvent1 =
            std::is_same<decltype(Visitor::OnEvent1(*this)),
                         AlgorithmBase::ResultOfHandlingEvent1>::value;
        handleEvent1(std::integral_constant<bool, ReturnTypeFlagOfOnEvent1>());

        constexpr bool ReturnTypeFlagOfOnEvent2 =
            std::is_same<decltype(Visitor::OnEvent2(*this)),
                         AlgorithmBase::ResultOfHandlingEvent2>::value;
        handleEvent2(std::integral_constant<bool, ReturnTypeFlagOfOnEvent2>());
    }

private:
    void handleEvent1(std::true_type) {
        auto res = Visitor::OnEvent1((AlgorithmBase &)*this);
        std::cout << "Will switch on the result of handling event 1!"
                  << std::endl;
        (void)res; // but a switch statement will appear here
    }
    void handleEvent1(std::false_type) {
        Visitor::OnEvent1((AlgorithmBase &)*this);
        std::cout << "Nothing to be done for the result of handling event 1!"
                  << std::endl;
    }

    void handleEvent2(std::true_type) {
        auto res = Visitor::OnEvent2((AlgorithmBase &)*this);
        std::cout << "Will switch on the result of handling event 2!"
                  << std::endl;
        (void)res; // but a switch statement will appear here
    }
    void handleEvent2(std::false_type) {
        Visitor::OnEvent2((AlgorithmBase &)*this);
        std::cout << "Nothing to be done for the result of handling event 2!"
                  << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Let's give it a test run:

```
int main() {
    Algorithm<UserVisitor> a;
    a.run();
    return 0;
}
```

We get the output:

```
In VisitorForEvent1! data1 = 5
Will switch on the result of handling event 1!
Nothing to be done for the result of handling event 2!
```

**THE REQUEST**

I am a researcher myself and am learning C++ for this project. Hence, I would like to ask the experts here to point out to me if I made mistakes that unseasoned designers and programmers tend to make. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What excites you so much about that *design*?

Comment: @skypjack Well, it's new to me! Would you be excited about having eyes had you got them today for the first time? I think so. Would your excitement be diminished  by the fact that everyone else got them a long time ago? I don't think so.

Comment: Got it, chapeau. :-)